# NestedScrollView fading/moving views in/out on Scroll Up/Down

Tags: java, android, kotlin, alpha, android-nestedscrollview

I have a nested scroll view with child views (wrapped in layout) and I need to fade in/out on scroll up/down.

My issue is trying to get the vertical scroll value reversed (to lessen the alpha value for fading in and out on scroll).

> As standard, the ScrollY (vertical Scroll value) increases/starts from
>   0 as the user scrolls to the bottom of the NestedScroll from the Top

I'm sure there would is a math equation to get the correct value for alpha fading in/out but cant quite stick it but once I do, I could also get values to move views up/down and fade in/out on scroll.

Not wanting to use CoordinatedLayout to collapse etc

**NestedScroll View (XML)**

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <!-- Fade In/Out -->
                    <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/fade_me_on_scroll"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                    </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Fragment with NestedScroll View in onCreateView (Kotlin)**

```
 //...
 //...
 //...
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

   //...
   //...
   //region NestedScroll
    myNestedScroll = binding.NestedScroll 

    if (myNestedScroll != null) {
        myNestedScroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(
            NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->

                //set Scroll Calculation Factor, use in calculation
                var scrollCalculateFactor = 25

                //set Scroll min range, if ScrollY has passed this value, do processing in the if statement below
                var minScrollRange = 10

                //set Scroll max range, if ScrollY has passed this value, stop processing
                var maxScrollRange = 250

                //if scroll is with range, do processing
                if(scrollY in minScrollRange..maxScrollRange) {

                    //wrap in try block just in case it goes paer shaped ...
                    try {

                      //set current ScrollY value to alpha value
                      //issue is here, works correctly as it returns the alpha value (i.e 0.20f)
                      //but as user scrolls to the Bottom the value (alpha) increases which fades in views (and as user scroll to the Top, fades out views), but I need the opposite to happen so views fade in/out correctly
                      var currentCalculatedAlpha = scrollY.toFloat() / maxScrollRange.toFloat()

                      if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                          //region Scrolling to the Bottom
                          //fade views out here

                          //fade the View using alpha setting
                          //however as the scrollY value increases, the alpha increases, fading in the view, need to opposite to happen
                          //binding.FadeMeOnScroll.alpha = currentCalculatedAlpha 

                          //endregion Scrolling to the Bottom
                      } else if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
                          //region Scrolling to the Top
                          //fade views back in

                          //fade the View using alpha setting
                          //however as the scrollY value decreases, the alpha decreases, fading out the view, need to opposite to happen
                          //binding.FadeMeOnScroll.alpha = currentCalculatedAlpha 

                          //endregion Scrolling to the Top
                      } else if(scrollY >= maxScrollRange){
                          //region Scrolled passed max range
                          //stop processing or manually fade out 

                          //fade the View using alpha setting
                          //binding.FadeMeOnScroll.alpha = 0f 

                          //endregion Scrolled passed max range
                      }

                    }catch (exception: Exception) {
                      //log error  
                      Log.e("exception", "exception: " + exception.message)
                    }

                }

            })
    }

    //endregion NestedScroll

}
```

Comment: Worse case I could run an single animation to fadeslide in/out views each time a certain  threshold is reached, not ideal as I wish to have acute control over the views per scroll position

Comment: If you need opposite, I think you can do something like 
`binding.FadeMeOnScroll.alpha = 1 - currentCalculatedAlpha`  
subtracting from 1 will give kind of inverse effect for currently calculated alpha.Or, correct me, if I understand your question wrong?

Comment: Works like a charm, views now fade in/out as intended +1